# I cant get data from my firestore db using geofirestore in express

Tags: javascript, express, google-cloud-firestore, geofirestore

I created a query in express to extract my data
this is my express function for endpoint:

```
app.get('/locatii', (req, res) => {
    const geofirestore = new GeoFirestore(db);
    const geocollection = geofirestore.collection('locatii2');
    const query = geocollection.near({
        center: new firebase.firestore.GeoPoint(45.831922, 27.431149),
        radius: 3000
    });
    query.get().then(snap => {
        console.log(snap.docs())
        let places = [];
        snap.forEach(doc => {
            places.push(doc.data());
            console.log(doc.data())
        });
        res.json(places);
    })
        .catch(err => res.send(err));
});
```

below it's my firesore structure:[image: database structure]
When I acces my endpoint it don't shows in console data or in postman.I don't know what I missed.Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your data structure doesn't seem to have a geohash in it. Having a geohash in each document is required for being able to query those documents by their location.

From the [example app](https://github.com/geofirestore/geofirestore-js/blob/master/examples/viewers) that come with GeoFirestoreJS, it seems that you can [get the geohash](https://github.com/geofirestore/geofirestore-js/blob/master/examples/viewers/js/viewers.js#L46) with something like:

```
location.lat = ...
location.lng = ...
const hash = geokit.Geokit.hash(location);
```

And then set it into your Firestore document with something like:

```
documentRef.update(hash);
```

Comment: `geokit` is an external library, you'll need to install it from npm => https://www.npmjs.com/package/geokit